# AngularJS string compare

Tags: angularjs

Having a weird issue with angular string compare. I am trying to compare two file names to see whether an uploaded file is new or an update.

Code looks like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.azureFilesData.length; i++) {
        console.log("Check Existing File Name: " + $scope.azureFilesData[i].file_name + ", Against upload File Name: " + fileName);

        if (angular.equals($scope.azureFilesData[i].file_name.toUpperCase,fileName.toUpperCase)) {
            console.log("Confirm Existing File Name: " + $scope.azureFilesData[i].file_name + "Equals upload File Name: " + fileName);
            return $scope.azureFilesData[i].azurefilesid;
        }
    }
```

Upload a first file where the azureFilesData is empty, it skips this block. Upload a second file, and the Console reports:

> Check Existing File Name: Upload Test 2.docx, Against upload File Name: Upload Test.docx
>   Confirm Existing File Name: Upload Test 2.docxEquals upload File Name: Upload Test.docx

But it returns the ID of the first (only, since everything after the first file thinks it is an update). I have also tried substituting == and === instead of the angular.equals. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `fileName` variable defined as `fileName = 'Upload Test.docx'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toUpperCase` is a function so you need to invoke it like `fileName.toUpperCase()` or else you will be comparing the functions.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something little. Appreciate you taking the time to look.